# Rotate path data

Tags: c#, wpf

This tiny little path data `M 0 0 L 3.5 4 L 7 0 Z` represents a very nice DownArrow:

[image]

How can I get the UpArrow path data from this, ie turn it 180°?

Comment: Set the Path's RenderTransform property to an appropriate RotateTransform, or if it is a Geometry, set its Transform property.

Comment: I'd like the calculated path data..

Comment: That's trivial. Replace the y values by their negatives, i.e. `4` by `-4`.

Comment: But why don't you simply use a RotateTransform? You can even apply this with a trigger so you don't need to use 2 different Paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path is read as follow :

`M` is start of path , `Z` in end of path, `L` is a new point

```
M X1 Y1 L X2 Y2 L X3 Y3 Z
```

So Down arrow is :`M 0 0 L 3.5 4 L 7 0 Z`

then Up arrow is : `M 0 0 L 3.5 -4 L 7 0 Z`

Left can be : `M 0 0 L -4 -3.5 L 0 -7 Z`

And Right can be : `M 0 0 L 4 -3.5 L 0 -7 Z`

Edit : note that the Y increase as you go DOWN the screen and not like typical Cartesian graph

Answer (score 1):

Replace each y co-ordinate with 4 - y, giving ...

```
M 0 4 L 3.5 0 L 7 4 Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the path data describes where the line starts: At x=0, y=0 (M 0 0) than going to x=3.5, y=4 continuing to x=7, y=0 and closing back to the origin with Z.
So drawing the same arrow upwards you start at x=0, y=4 going to x=3.5, y=0, than x=7, y=4 than return

```
M 0 4 L 3.5 0 L 7 4 Z
```